Term SOFR rates and OIS SOFR rates
On Bloomberg terminal, plotting the 1M Term SOFR against the 1M SOFR OIS rate (i.e. TSFR1M Index and USOSFRA Curncy) shows two lines on top of each other, with some rare occasions of notable basis. This also happens with the 3M rates.
What is the economic rationale behind the 0-ish basis between these two rates?

i think 1m term SOFRs are implied from 1m SFR futures and compiled/published by CME (I am not entirely sure this rate is even tradable). The actual 1m SOFR rate is from the SOFR OIS swap (Fixed vs compounded OIS).

@user68819 That's right. Given they are from two different markets but with some connections I'm curious what's the binding force that led to my observations (and perhaps insight into when that might break).

well the binding force is almost certainly the fact that a dealer would use the futures as a reference to price the swaps. In my opinion the 1m futures aren't the most liquid, so actually the FedFund futures would probably be a reference along with some FF/SOFR basis added (as again, that is a fairly liquid market at the short end). With regards to when the two break, I am not entirely sure, there may be something specific in the calculation, but i doubt it would deviate too far (if it is a meaningful measure).

@user68819 I'm under the impression that term sofr is only significant due to its role as the reference index for $$$ of floating instruments. But if itself (or where it's derived from) isn't heavily trade and rather is "supposed to" track the more liquid alternative (be it sofr ois or ff ois + sofr basis), that would certainly be good to know. The most basis I've seen btw is ~15 bps sometime a year or two ago iirc.

I'd agree with that.
